# React Native set input focus

Tags: react-native

How can I set focus to an Input in react native?

I have some inputs in my code:

```
<Input
   value={CompName}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'CompName')}
   style={styles.valueText}
/>
<Input
   value={Phone}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'Phone')}
   style={styles.valueText}
/>
...
```

And I validate if it is empty. IF empty, I set a Alert message and I would like to focus on the field. How can I do it?

```
myFunc = () => {
  if(CompName === '' || CompName === undefined){
     Alert.alert('Company Name is required.');
     // set focus here??
     return;
  }
  ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, in react-native, it is `TextInput`. and here is two methods exposed via the native element. they are .focus() and .blur() that will focus or blur the TextInput programmatically.

for use it, you have to set a ref for the `TextInput`.

```
<TextInput
   value={this.state.compName}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'CompName')}
   style={styles.valueText}
   ref={(input) => { this.compNameInput = input; }}
/>
myFunc = () => {
  if(this.state.compName === '' || this.state.comNam === undefined){
     Alert.alert('Company Name is required.');
     // set focus here??
     this.compNameInput.focus();
     return;
  }
  ...
}
```

I suggest use the state for the `compName`, like `this.state.compName`